# getting started angularjs failed

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Not sure why is this not working

https://jsfiddle.net/0616b9ks

```
<body ng-app="main" id="homepage">
  <h1 ng-controller="homepageCtrl">hello {{test}}</h1>
</body>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module("main", [])

.controller("homepageCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.test = "World!";
});
```

Comment: You should start by including `angular.js`

Comment: include angular in you fiddle :)

Comment: I alrdy did, look at this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Lt7aP/4/, does it use the script tag? no right?

Comment: @HarisZ It does use Angular 1.2.1 with LoadType as onLoad

Comment: @PirateX and mine too https://jsfiddle.net/0616b9ks/

Comment: @AlonEitan I think I did? https://jsfiddle.net/0616b9ks/

Comment: @HarisZ, answered.

Comment: take a look on this thanks https://github.com/eldyvoon/temp

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine. It's the jsfiddle which was creating the trouble.

Switch the load type from `onLoad` to `No Wrap - in <head>`
Just tested it on your fiddle. Works like a charm.

**Why it works?** 
JsFiddle wraps the code in a ready or load event by default & Angular may not get what it needs in the global scope when compiling your code. `No wrap in <head>` just loads the script in the head, without a wrap.

Give this a read if you use jsfiddle a lot for Angular, it'll save you a lot time- [Using jsFiddle with Angular](https://pkozlowskios.wordpress.com/2012/08/12/using-jsfiddle-with-angularjs/)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Js Fidle Switch the load type from onLoad to No Wrap - in